# How to export an Anchor defined enum to Typescript?

Tags: anchor, typescript

I have an enum used in one of my account that looks like this:

```
#[derive(AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize, Clone)]
pub enum ItemType {
    Empty,
    Folder { folder_mint: Pubkey },
    Reference { folder_mint: Pubkey },
    External { uri: String },
}

#[account]
pub struct Item {
    /// Used as seed
    pub folder_mint: Pubkey,
    /// Used as seed
    pub index: u32,
    pub previous_index: u32,
    pub creation_timestamp: i64,
    pub item_type: ItemType,
}
```

I know I can export the account like so:
`export type Item = IdlAccounts<MyProgram>["item"];`

But how can I export the enum type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think you can use : `type myEnum = IdlTypes<ProgramIdl>["enumName"]`